Cambio de zona horaria en servidor Oracle Solaris 5.10
Tengo una maquina (Servidor) con el sistema operativo SunOS 5.10 SOLARIS Necesito realizar el cambio de zona horaria del servidor. La maquina Oracle Solaris 5.10 Muestra la hora de la siguiente manera:
Thu Apr 25 12:43:50 COT 2024
Y Quiero mostrar la fecha de la siguiente manera:
25/04/2024  11:00:00 a. m. UTC  es decir cambiar el formato y zona horaria del servidor.
